# PrivateOutlet.js doesn't render page after authentication

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

When I try the below code I get redirected to login page as if I'm not authenticated. Once I login I can't view the about page as it directs me to Welcome page because the logic in login page (if `isAuthenticated` navigates to Welcome page). If I remove the logic in login page I get stuck in login page only. Why I can't view about page?

PrivateOutlet.js ;

```
import React from 'react';
import { Outlet, Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';

const PrivateOutlet = ({ isAuthenticated }) => {
  if (isAuthenticated ) { 
    return <Outlet /> 
  } else {
    return <Navigate to='login' /> //Go to login
  }
};

export default PrivateOutlet;
```

updated PrivateOutlet.js ;

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Outlet, Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';

const PrivateOutlet = ({ isAuthenticated }) => {
  return isAuthenticated ? <Outlet /> : <Navigate to='/login' replace />;
};
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    isAuthenticated: state.auth.isAuthenticated
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(PrivateOutlet);
```

App.js

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Router>
        <Layout>
          <Routes>
            <Route path='/' element={<WelcomePage/>} />
            <Route path='/home' element={<Home/>} />

            <Route element={<PrivateOutlet/>}>
              <Route path='/about' element={<About/>} />
            </Route>

            <Route path='/contact' element={<Contact/>} />
            <Route path='/login' element={<Login/>} />
            <Route path='/signup' element={<Signup/>} />
            <Route path='/reset-password' element={<ResetPassword/>} />
            <Route path='/password/reset/confirm/:uid/:token' element={<ResetPasswordConfirm/>} />
            <Route path='/activate/:uid/:token' element={<Activate/>} />
            <Route path='*' element={<NotFound/>} />
          </Routes>
        </Layout>
      </Router>
    </Provider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

login.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Link, Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Button } from '@mui/material';
import { login } from '../actions/auth';
import './Login.css';
import { Helmet } from 'react-helmet';

function Login({ login, isAuthenticated }) {
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    email: '',
    password: ''
  });

  const { email, password } = formData;
  const onChange = e => setFormData({ ...formData, [e.target.name]: e.target.value});
  const onSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    login (email, password)
  };
 
  if (isAuthenticated) {
    return <Navigate to='/' />
  }

  return (
    <div className='login'>
      <Helmet>
        <title>Prosperity - Login</title>
        <meta
          name='description'
          content='login page'
        />
      </Helmet>
      <h1 className='login__title'>Login</h1>
      <p className='login__lead'>Login into your Account</p>
      <form className='login__form' onSubmit={e => onSubmit(e)}>
        <div className='login__form__group'>
          <input
            className='login__form__input'
            type='email'
            placeholder='Email *'
            name='email'
            value={email}
            onChange={e => onChange(e)}
            required
          />
        </div>
        <div className='login__form__group'>
          <input
            className='login__form__input'
            type='password'
            placeholder='Password *'
            name='password'
            value={password}
            onChange={e => onChange(e)}
            minLength='8'
            required
          />
        </div>
        <Button className='login__button__main' type='submit'>Login</Button>
      </form>
      <p className='link__to__Signup'>
        Do not have an account? <Link to='/signup' className='login__link'>Register</Link>
      </p>
      <p className='link__to__resetPassword'>
        Forgot Password? <Link to='/reset-password' className='reset__password__link'>Reset Password</Link>
      </p>

    </div>
  )
};
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  isAuthenticated: state.auth.isAuthenticated
});

export default connect (mapStateToProps, { login }) (Login);
```

actions/Auth.js ;

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { setAlert } from './alert';
import {
    LOGIN_SUCCESS,
    LOGIN_FAIL,
    SIGNUP_SUCCESS,
    SIGNUP_FAIL,
    ACTIVATION_SUCCESS,
    ACTIVATION_FAIL,
    USER_LOADED_SUCCESS,
    USER_LOADED_FAIL,
    AUTHENTICATED_SUCCESS,
    AUTHENTICATED_FAIL,
    PASSWORD_RESET_SUCCESS,
    PASSWORD_RESET_FAIL,
    PASSWORD_RESET_CONFIRM_SUCCESS,
    PASSWORD_RESET_CONFIRM_FAIL,
    LOGOUT
} from './types';

export const checkAuthenticated = () => async dispatch => {
    if (localStorage.getItem('access')) {
        const config = {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Accept': 'application/json'
            }
        };

        const body = JSON.stringify({ token: localStorage.getItem('access') });

        try {
            const res = await axios.post(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/auth/jwt/verify/`, body, config)

            if (res.data.code !== 'token_not_valid') {
                dispatch({
                    type: AUTHENTICATED_SUCCESS
                });
            } else {
                dispatch({
                    type: AUTHENTICATED_FAIL
                });
            }
        } catch (err) {
            dispatch({
                type: AUTHENTICATED_FAIL
            });
        }

    } else {
        dispatch({
            type: AUTHENTICATED_FAIL
        });
    }
};

export const load_user = () => async dispatch => {
    if (localStorage.getItem('access')) {
        const config = {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': `JWT ${localStorage.getItem('access')}`,
                'Accept': 'application/json'
            }
        }; 
        
        try {
            const res = await axios.get(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/auth/users/me/`, config);
            dispatch({
                type: USER_LOADED_SUCCESS,
                payload: res.data
            });
        }catch (err) {
            dispatch({
                type: USER_LOADED_FAIL
            });
        }
    } else {
        dispatch({
            type: USER_LOADED_FAIL
        });
    }
};

export const login = (email, password) => async dispatch => {
    const config = {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    };

    const body = JSON.stringify({ email, password });

    try {
            const res = await axios.post(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/auth/jwt/create/`, body, config);
            dispatch({
                type: LOGIN_SUCCESS,
                payload: res.data
            });
            dispatch(setAlert('Authenticated successfully', 'success'));
            dispatch(load_user());
        }catch (err) {
            dispatch({
                type: LOGIN_FAIL
            });
            dispatch(setAlert('Error Authenticating', 'error'));
    }
};

export const signup = (name, email, password, re_password) => async dispatch => {
    const config = {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    };

    const body = JSON.stringify({ name, email, password, re_password });

    try {
        const res = await axios.post(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/auth/users/`, body, config);

        dispatch({
            type: SIGNUP_SUCCESS,
            payload: res.data
        });
        dispatch(setAlert('Check Your Email to Activate Your Account.', 'warning'));
    } catch (err) {
        dispatch({
            type: SIGNUP_FAIL
        })
    }
};

export const verify = (uid, token) => async dispatch => {
    const config = {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    };

    const body = JSON.stringify({ uid, token });

    try {
        await axios.post(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/auth/users/activation/`, body, config);

        dispatch({
            type: ACTIVATION_SUCCESS,
        });
        dispatch(setAlert('Account Activated Successfully.', 'success'));
    } catch (err) {
        dispatch({
            type: ACTIVATION_FAIL
        })
    }
};

//Reset Password
export const reset_password = (email) => async dispatch => {
    const config = {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    };

    const body = JSON.stringify({ email });
    try {
        await axios.post (`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/auth/users/reset_password/`, body, config);
        dispatch({
            type: PASSWORD_RESET_SUCCESS
        });
        dispatch(setAlert('Check Your Email to Rest Password.', 'warning'));
    } catch (err) {
        dispatch({
            type: PASSWORD_RESET_FAIL
        });
    }
};

// Reset Password Confirm
export const reset_password_confirm = (uid, token, new_password, re_new_password) => async dispatch => {
    const config = {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    };

    const body = JSON.stringify({ uid, token, new_password, re_new_password });
    
    try {
        await axios.post (`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/auth/users/reset_password_confirm/`, body, config);
        dispatch(setAlert('Password Rest Successful.', 'success'));
        dispatch({
            type: PASSWORD_RESET_CONFIRM_SUCCESS
        });
    } catch (err) {
        dispatch({
            type: PASSWORD_RESET_CONFIRM_FAIL
        });
    }
};

//Logout
export const logout = () => dispatch => {
    dispatch(setAlert('Logout successful.', 'success'));
    dispatch({
        type: LOGOUT
    });
};
```

reducers/Auth.js ;

```
import {
    LOGIN_SUCCESS,
    LOGIN_FAIL,
    SIGNUP_SUCCESS,
    SIGNUP_FAIL,
    ACTIVATION_SUCCESS,
    ACTIVATION_FAIL,
    USER_LOADED_SUCCESS,
    USER_LOADED_FAIL,
    AUTHENTICATED_SUCCESS,
    AUTHENTICATED_FAIL,
    PASSWORD_RESET_SUCCESS,
    PASSWORD_RESET_FAIL,
    PASSWORD_RESET_CONFIRM_SUCCESS,
    PASSWORD_RESET_CONFIRM_FAIL,
    LOGOUT
} from '../actions/types';

const initialState = {
    access: localStorage.getItem('access'),
    refresh: localStorage.getItem('refresh'),
    isAuthenticated: null,
    user: null,
};

export default function (state = initialState, action) {
    const { type, payload } = action;

    switch(type) {
        case AUTHENTICATED_SUCCESS:
            return {
                ...state,
                isAuthenticated: true
            }
        case LOGIN_SUCCESS:
            localStorage.setItem('access', payload.access);
            localStorage.setItem('refresh', payload.refresh);
            return {
                ...state,
                isAuthenticated: true,
                access: payload.access,
                refresh: payload.refresh,
            }
        case USER_LOADED_SUCCESS:
            return {
                ...state,
                user: payload
            }
        case SIGNUP_SUCCESS:
            return {
                ...state,
                isAuthenticated: false,
            }
        case AUTHENTICATED_FAIL:
            return {
                ...state,
                isAuthenticated: false
            }
        case USER_LOADED_FAIL:
            return {
                ...state,
                user: null
            }
        case LOGIN_FAIL:
        case SIGNUP_FAIL:
        case LOGOUT:
            localStorage.removeItem('access');
            localStorage.removeItem('refresh');
            return {
                ...state,
                access: null,
                refresh: null,
                isAuthenticated: false,
                user: null,
            }
        case PASSWORD_RESET_SUCCESS:
        case PASSWORD_RESET_FAIL:
        case ACTIVATION_SUCCESS:
        case ACTIVATION_FAIL:
        case PASSWORD_RESET_CONFIRM_SUCCESS:
        case PASSWORD_RESET_CONFIRM_FAIL:
            return {
                ...state
            }

        default:
            return state
    }
};
```

Comment: `isAuthenticated` isn't passed as a prop to `PrivateOutlet`. Is it supposed to get that value from Redux?

Comment: How do you go to the about page? enter the URL or by a `Link` tag or `useNavigate`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`isAuthenticated` isn't passed as a prop to PrivateOutlet.

```
<Route element={<PrivateOutlet />}> // <-- no isAuthenticated prop
  <Route path='/about' element={<About />} />
</Route>
```

`isAuthenticated` is stored in redux state and the initial value is `null` ***and not*** the `true`|`false` after a successful or failed authentication attempt.

```
const initialState = {
  access: localStorage.getItem('access'),
  refresh: localStorage.getItem('refresh'),
  isAuthenticated: null,
  user: null,
};
```

You can explicitly check if the `isAuthenticated` state is `null` and conditionally return null or a loading indicator, etc... while the authentication status is being resolved. Once the authentication status resolves to a non-null value then either the routed component or redirect can be rendered.

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Outlet, Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';

const PrivateOutlet = ({ isAuthenticated }) => {
  if (isAuthenticated === null) {
    return null;
  }
  return isAuthenticated ? <Outlet /> : <Navigate to='/login' replace />;
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  isAuthenticated: state => state.auth.isAuthenticated,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(PrivateOutlet);
```

or

```
import React from 'react';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { Outlet, Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';

const PrivateOutlet = () => {
  const isAuthenticated = useSelector(state => state.auth.isAuthenticated);

  if (isAuthenticated === null) {
    return null;
  }
  return isAuthenticated ? <Outlet /> : <Navigate to='/login' replace />;
};

export default PrivateOutlet;
```

### Update

If you want to redirect a user back to the page they were originally trying to access the `PrivateOutlet` component should grab the current location and pass this in route state to the login page.

```
import { Outlet, Navigate, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

const PrivateOutlet = () => {
  const location = useLocation();
  const isAuthenticated = useSelector(state => state.auth.isAuthenticated);

  if (isAuthenticated === null) {
    return null;
  }
  return isAuthenticated
    ? <Outlet />
    : <Navigate to='/login' state={{ from: location }} replace />;
};
```

Then the `Login` component grabs this value from route state to imperatively navigate back to the original route.

```
const navigate = useNavigate();
const { state } = useLocation();
const { from } = state || {};

...

navigate(from.pathname || "/home", { state: from.state, replace: true });
```

#### Example

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Link, Navigate, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
...

function Login({ login, isAuthenticated }) {
  const { state } = useLocation();
  const { from } = state || {};

  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    email: '',
    password: ''
  });

  const { email, password } = formData;

  const onChange = e => setFormData({
    ...formData,
    [e.target.name]: e.target.value
  });

  const onSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    login(email, password);
  };
 
  if (isAuthenticated) {
    return (
      <Navigate
        to={from.pathname || "/home"}
        replace
        state={from.state}
      />
    );
  }

  return (
    ...
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  isAuthenticated: state.auth.isAuthenticated
});
```

### Update 2

> I get on the console; `Login.js:30 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'pathname')`

I think what is occurring here is that the `login` action updates your redux store, which *should* trigger the component to rerender, and I suspect it's *this* rerender that looses the route state. Route state is pretty transient and only exists during the transition and render cycle when it's received. You could probably use a React ref to cache a copy of the route state to use later.

Example:

```
import React, { useRef, useState } from 'react';
import { Link, Navigate, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
...

function Login({ login, isAuthenticated }) {
  const { state } = useLocation();
  const { from } = state || {};

  const fromRef = useRef(from);

  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    email: '',
    password: ''
  });

  const { email, password } = formData;

  const onChange = e => setFormData({
    ...formData,
    [e.target.name]: e.target.value
  });

  const onSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    login(email, password);
  };
 
  if (isAuthenticated) {
    return (
      <Navigate
        to={fromRef.current.pathname || "/home"}
        replace
        state={fromRef.current.state}
      />
    );
  }

  return (
    ...
  );
};
```

It may be more practical to pass an "onLoginSuccess" handler to the `login` action, and issue an imperative navigation from the asynchronous action.

Example:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Link, useNavigate, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
...

function Login({ login, isAuthenticated }) {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const { state } = useLocation();
  const { from } = state || {};

  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    email: '',
    password: ''
  });

  const { email, password } = formData;

  const onChange = e => setFormData({
    ...formData,
    [e.target.name]: e.target.value
  });

  const onSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const onSuccess = () => {
      navigate(
        from.pathname || "/home",
        {
          replace: true,
          state: from.state
        }
      );
    };

    login(email, password, onSuccess);
  };
 
  return (
    ...
  );
};
```

...

```
export const login = (email, password, onSuccess) => async dispatch => {
  const config = {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
  };

  const body = JSON.stringify({ email, password });

  try {
    const res = await axios.post(
      `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/auth/jwt/create/`,
      body,
      config
    );
    dispatch({ type: LOGIN_SUCCESS, payload: res.data });
    dispatch(setAlert('Authenticated successfully', 'success'));
    dispatch(load_user());
    if (onSuccess) {
      onSuccess();
    }
  } catch (err) {
    dispatch({ type: LOGIN_FAIL });
    dispatch(setAlert('Error Authenticating', 'error'));
  }
};
```

Comment: Hi Drew, Thanks for your reply. You are right, isAuthenticated is part of redux store. but still I can't access about page. I get redirected to login. 2nd solution redirects to login, the first make it accessible to all without authentication unless i change const mapStateToProps as below but then it only takes me to login page;
```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  isAuthenticated: state.auth.isAuthenticated
});
```

Comment: @Moammer I see. I suspect your initial state likely masks, or matches, your unauthenticated state. Can you update your question to include your reducer/state slice code so we can see the initial state value and the actions that update it? Do you use any sort of state persistence of your redux store?

Comment: Hi Drew, I added actions/Auth.js and reducers/Auth.js above. I really appreciate your support! Many Thanks.

Comment: Hi Drew, Many thanks. Now It functions as expected. but it once logged, it's doesn't save the location of the about page. I have to type the link to go to the about page. Again, Many Many thanks for your help